# Displaying a page in MVC 3 without layout

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a page that generates a printable table. I need to show this page without my surrounding `_Layout` page, for printer-friendliness.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Assuming you use razor view engine (you mentioned *layout*, not *master page*)

```
@{
    Layout = null;
 }
```

Well actually you should use razor view engine but anyways, idea is simple. Do not specify (remove) master page file reference in your aspx view and remove all ContentPlaceHolders, write all content directly in page. Or there's another way if you don't wish to remove them for some reason. Make `PrintMaster.master` master page which will contain nothing but ContentPlaceHolders.

Comment: I use the classic ASPX view engine actually. And there actually is a master page. Sorry about that.

Comment: This is work releated, and the project i'm working on is exclusively using the ASPX view engine for some reason. Nothing i can do.

Answer (score 4):

```
While creating a new view, you can uncheck the use layout checkbox. 
This will create you a view with layout as null.

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create the view it allows you to change the Master Page. If you unmark the checkbox, the view comes with no Master Page and you can modify the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to support displaying results on a page as well as having a printable view, you could create a second view (named `PrintView` for example) that does not use a page layout and call `return View("PrintView");` from your controller.

Answer (score 0):

A standard print style action can be done in several ways. 
1. use a different view with a print button that sets the layout to null assuming you can map to razor.

To do this with CSS - you will want a separate css file that will be loaded on print and will hide your masterpage items. See the various articles on keywords
css media print
for example:
http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/a/aa042103a.htm

This uses

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

with the key here being media="print" which will use that css during print only.